# How I can pass argument to callback function of addEventListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add to listener one for window and another for element and the two must be enable when the drop menu appear,
so I got the ref to the element(scroll), and I need to pass it in the callback function to remove the listener,

```
 <a
     href="#"
     onClick={e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      this.openMenu(scroll);
    }}
   >
    <i className="fas fa-ellipsis-h" />
 </a>

openMenu = (scroll,e) => {
 this.setState(prevState => ({ showMenu: !prevState.showMenu }),
  () => {
    document.addEventListener("click", this.closeMenu);
    scroll.addEventListener('scroll',() => this.closeMenu(scroll))
   }
);
};

  closeMenu = (scroll,e) => {
    this.setState({ showMenu: false }, () => {
     document.removeEventListener("click", this.closeMenu);
     scroll.removeEventListener('scroll',() => this.closeMenu(scroll))
    });
   };
```

in this case I can't remove the listener because he didn't has the same name with the original one, so how can I solve it?

Comment: If you need to pass a parameter other than even object, wrap the event handler in an anonymous function bound to eventListener Also arrow function do not have `this` (or `new`) keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in this situation it is OK to remove the event handlers even before the state was updated. That allows you to "inline" the event handler removal:

```
openMenu = (scroll,e) => {
  this.setState(
    prevState => ({ showMenu: !prevState.showMenu }),
    () => {
      const component = this;
      function handler() {
        component.closeMenu();
        document.removeEventListener('click', handler);
        scroll.removeEventListener('scroll', handler);
      }
      document.addEventListener('click', handler);
      scroll.addEventListener('scroll', handler);
    }
  );
};

closeMenu = () => {
  this.setState({ showMenu: false });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider defining a shared `scrollHandler` function with the component class instance "as needed", which is passed to both `addEventListener()` and `removeEventListener()` when adding and removing the listener for `scroll`.

This approach allows you to retain the context or "closure" of `openMenu()` inside of the scroll event handler, meaning you can pass the `scroll` variable through to `this.closeMenu`:

```
openMenu = (scroll,e) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({ showMenu: !prevState.showMenu }),
  () => {
    document.addEventListener("click", this.closeMenu);

    /*
    Define a scrollHandler in this closure with "scroll" passed to closeMenu().
    Use this scrollHandler reference for both addEventListener() and subsequent
    removeEventListener() call
    */
    this.scrollHandler = () => this.closeMenu(scroll);

    /*
    Pass scrollHandler as handler for scroll event
    */
    scroll.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollHandler)
  }
  );
};

closeMenu = (scroll,e) => {
  this.setState({ showMenu: false }, () => {
    document.removeEventListener("click", this.closeMenu);

    /*
    If scrollHandler is defined, remove it as a handler from the element's scroll 
    event, and clear the reference to clean up
    */
    if(this.scrollHandler) {
        scroll.removeEventListener('scroll',this.scrollHandler)
        this.scrollHandler = undefined;
    }
  });
};
```

Hope this helps!